# Ошибка в токене ,не понимаю почему, выдает '' Token is invalid! It must be 'str' type instead of <class 'NoneType'> type."

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

import os

bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('тут токен'))
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_send(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)
    # await message.reply(message.text)
    # await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, mesage.text)
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)`
```

Comment: `bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('тут токен'))` - вместо 'тут токен' должна быть переменная окружения, где у вас токен записан, или должно быть `bot = Bot(token='тут токен')` без getenv, если вы прописываете токен в коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь прочитать переменную из `os.getenv`, которой не существует.

Ваш код может выглядеть примерно так:

```py
# тут импорты...
import os

bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('5737447:Auyfufy8786HjhYddyty627397'))
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
# тут главный код...
```

(*токен выдуман*)

который пытается прочитать переменную `5737447:Auyfufy8786HjhYddyty627397` из окружения (например, Bash).

---

Разве это правильно? Нет. Поэтому есть несколько вариантов решения именно этой проблемы:

*Во всех последующих примерах, замените `5737447:Auyfufy8786HjhYddyty627397` на свой токен.*

1. Либо сделать переменную окружения:

   Когда вы запускаете скрипт, передайте переменную окружения:

   ```bash
   TOKEN="5737447:Auyfufy8786HjhYddyty627397" python main.py
   ```

   или в две строки:

   ```bash
   TOKEN="5737447:Auyfufy8786HjhYddyty627397"
   python main.py
   ```

   (Вместо `main.py` поместите настоящее имя файла, в котором написан код бота.)

   А в главном файле, замените это:

   ```py
   bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('5737447:Auyfufy8786HjhYddyty627397'))
   ```

   на:

   ```py
   bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('TOKEN'))
   ```
2. Либо просто вставить токен в файл, и "не париться":
   Замените в файле это:

   ```py
   bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('5737447:Auyfufy8786HjhYddyty627397'))
   ```

   на это:

   ```py
   bot = Bot(token='5737447:Auyfufy8786HjhYddyty627397')
   ```

   Что я сделал? Я просто убрал `os.getenv()` из кода. Так тоже будет работать.
3. В [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1527239/548252) от [@Владислав Новосёлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/535272/%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%20%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) есть работающий способ. Можно также использовать его.

Comment: Спасибо это помогло

Comment: Был бы ещё признателен, если бы вы поставили плюс (стрелка вверх)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте создать отдельный python файл и создать в нём переменную с токеном так:

```
token = 'ваш_токен'
```

после импортируйте токен из нового файла в ваш основной, вместо того, чтобы пытаться достать его из системы через os:

```
from созданный_файл import token

bot = Bot(token=token)
```